# Numpy is working in Python, but not in Wing101 v. 7

Tags: python, numpy, pip

The location and name of the following file is:

c:\Users\Marielle\Oefeningen\untitled-2

```
import numpy, numpy.linalg
A = numpy.array([[2, 4], [5, -6]])
numpy.linalg.eigvals(A)
```

When I try this in Python, the result is: array([ 4., -8.])

But in Wing I get no result at all.

The sys.executable in Wing is allright

When I run sys.path in Wing it says:
['C:\Users\Mariëlle\Oefeningen', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages', 'C:/Users/Mariëlle/Oefeningen']

When I run sys.path in Python it says:
['', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39', 'C:\Users\Mariëlle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']

I installed numpy in Python with the command: pip3 install numpy

I really don't know how to make numpy work in Wing.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: try printing the value, `print(numpy.linalg.eigvals(A))`

Comment: Really, that simple! Wing did recognize numpy. Thank you very very much.Just one more little question. Why does Wing need a print-command and Python doesn’t?

Comment: my guess is that you were using the python [repl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). In the repl, you can simply type the name of the variable and the repl will output some information about it. This information is not always the same as if you were to `print(myvar)`. Hope that helps